# Convert array of objects into array of properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a simple way, using `filter` or `parse` or something else to convert an array like the following :

```
var someJsonArray = [
  {id: 0, name: "name", property: "value", otherproperties: "othervalues"},
  {id: 1, name: "name1", property: "value1", otherproperties: "othervalues1"},
  {id: 2, name: "name2", property: "value2", otherproperties: "othervalues2"}
];
```

into a simple array filled with one attribute of the objects contained in the previous array like this :

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: What about `someJsonArray.map(function(o) { return o.id; })` ? [Doc about map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I dont think return in a callback will even work.

Comment: @E.K Well [try it](https://jsfiddle.net/5t9f4qqr/) then...

Comment: I have edited the code in the above question to make it easy for developers! LoL. That's a sample code, which doesn't work.

Comment: Yea, my bad for the forgotten quotes since there is no accessible variable for the example. Thx

Comment: You can also use: `Array.from(arrayLike, x => x.foo)`

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
finalArray = someJsonArray.map(function (obj) {
  return obj.id;
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
var someJsonArray = [
  {id: 0, name: "name", property: "value", therproperties: "othervalues"},
  {id: 1, name: "name1", property: "value1", otherproperties: "othervalues1"},
  {id: 2, name: "name2", property: "value2", otherproperties: "othervalues2"}
];
var finalArray = someJsonArray.map(function (obj) {
  return obj.id;
});
console.log(finalArray);
```

The above snippet is changed to make it work.

Answer (score 21):

A more minimal example (ES6 onwards):

```
someJsonArray.map(({id}) => id)
```

Comment: this does not work as per the requirement in the question

Comment: @LGAP - could you explain - I've retested it against what was asked for, and it produces the exact result?

Comment: This works, but how? What is the significant of first & second `id`?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var len = someJsonArray.length, output = [];
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
   output.push(someJsonArray[i].id)
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i=0; i<someJsonArray.length; i++) {
    arr.push(someJsonArray[i].id);
}
```