# JS - how to convert all keys into its values (from objects)

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, type-conversion

I have something like this (im obtaining it from API, so I cant change it):

```
{ one: [ { price: ['$10'], weight: ['1000'], color: ['red'] } ],
  two: [ { price: ['$20'], weight: ['2000'], color: ['green'] } ],
  three: [ { price: ['$30'], weight: ['3000'], color: ['blue'] } ] }
```

And I want to convert all "price", "weight" and "color" keys to its values, to look like this:

```
{ one: [ '$10', '1000', 'red' ],
  two: [ '$20', '2000', 'green' ],
  three: [ '$30', '3000', 'blue' ] }
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Edit: Example fixed
Edit2: Wanted result fixed

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert to: `[ '$10', 1000, 'red' ]`? `[ { $10, 1000, red } ]` is not valid

Comment: The format you are trying to attain isn't valid data.

Comment: please add `[Object]`.

Comment: Ok, I will edit post soon. I will add these objects into example. // Done

Comment: This is quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/34309090/215552...

Comment: What have you tried so far? What have you considered?

Comment: @Chamov `{ '$10', '1000', 'red' }` still isn't valid.

Comment: @Jordan, yes. From what I think it should look like one: [ '$10', '1000', 'red' ],

Comment: @Chamov Please edit your question to show the (valid) result you actually want.

Comment: @Jordan, done :) And 1st answer from Nina Scholz seems to be what I wanted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map use the keys and map the wanted properties form the inner array.

```js
var object = { one: [ { price: ['$10'], weight: ['1000'], color: ['red'] } ], two: [ { price: ['$20'], weight: ['2000'], color: ['green'] } ], three: [ { price: ['$30'], weight: ['3000'], color: ['blue'] } ] };

Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
    object[k] = [ 'price', 'weight', 'color'].map(function (p) {
        return object[k][0][p][0];
    });
});

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Oh, and greetings from D-Dorf Reisholz :P